# How do you launch a new browser process from vbscript

Tags: browser, process, vbscript

I can launch the default browser (chrome) with

```
call WShell.Run("http://www.google.com", 1, false)
```

but if I try

```
call WShell.Run("http://www.google.com", 1, true)
```

I get an error:

> "unable to wait for process"

How can I launch a browser (could be IE or chrome) in a new process and wait for that process to exit.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395989/can-i-make-one-process-exit-when-another-does) for "why?"

Answer (score 3):

### 2019. VBS using HP UFT (QTP)

In HP UFT, I found few ways to run the browser via VBS.
My favorite is **SystemUtil.Run**.

1.SystemUtil.Run

```
    strURL = "www.google.com" 
    str_NavigateTo = "https://chesstempo.com/chess-tactics.html#5"
    int_mode_Maximized = 3         
    SystemUtil.Run "iexplore.exe",strURL, , ,3
    SystemUtil.Run "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE",  str_NavigateTo,"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer",  ,int_mode_Maximized
```

Where Mode & Description

- '0          Hides the window and activates another window.
- '1          Activates and displays the window. If the window is minimized or maximized, the system restores it to its original size
  and position. Specify this flag when displaying the window for the
  first time.
- '2          Activates the window and displays it as a minimized window.
- '**3**      -   Activates the window and displays it as a **maximized** window.
- '4          Displays the window in its most recent size and position. The active window remains active.
- '5          Activates the window and displays it in its current size and position.
- '6          Minimizes the specified window and activates
  the next top-level window in the Z order.
- '7          Displays the window as a minimized window. The active window remains active.
- '8          Displays the window in its current state. The active window remains active.
- '9          Activates and displays the window. If the window is minimized or maximized, the system restores it to its original size
  and position. Specify this flag when restoring a minimized window.
- '10     Sets the show-state based on the state of the program that started the application.

*Extra detailed descriptions of the SystemUtil parameters can be found here:
[SystemUtil.Run](https://www.learnqtp.com/forums/attachment.php?aid=767)


2. InvokeApplication

```
    InvokeApplication "C://Program Files/Internet Explorer/IEXPLORE.EXE http://www.wp.pl"
```

3. VBScript via WScript.shell
If the path to your executable contains spaces, use Chr(34) to ensure the path is contained within double quotes.

```
    Dim oShellSet oShell = CreateObject ("Wscript.shell")'
```

'Example 1 - run a batch file:

```
    oShell.run "F://jdk1.3.1/demo/jfc/SwingSet2.bat"
```

'Example 2 - run a Java jar file:

```
    oShell.run "java -jar F://jdk1.3.1/demo/jfc/SwingSet2/SwingSet2.jar"
```

'Example 3 - launch Internet Explorer:

```
    oShell.Run Chr(34) & "C://Program Files/Internet Explorer/IEXPLORE.EXE" & Chr(34) 

    Set oShell = Nothing
```

4. IE Automation Object Model

```
    Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    oIE.Navigate "http://www.google.com/"
    oIE.Visible = True
        ......
    Set oIE = Nothing
```

5. Use the Windows \ Start \ Run dialog.

- Add the Windows Start button to the Object Repository using the “Add Objects” button in Object Repository dialog.
- Open the Run dialog (Start -> Run), and learn the “Open” edit field and the “OK” button into the Object Repository.
- Switch to the Expert View, and manually add the lines to open the Run dialog.
  Example:

  ```
  Window("Window").WinButton("Button").ClickWindow("Window").Type("R")
  ```

  Manually enter the lines to enter the information to launch the application, and click the “OK” button of the Run dialog.
  Example:

  ```
  Dialog("Run").WinEdit("Open:").Type "C://Windows/System32/notepad.exe"
  Dialog("Run").WinButton("OK").Click
  ```

  6. WebUtil Object

In UFT 14.01 update, HPE introduced two new methods for WebUtil Object.
 LaunchBrowser and LaunchMobileBrowserWithID

```
    WebUtil.LaunchBrowser Browser, [device_model, device_manufacturer, device_ostype, device_osversion]
    WebUtil.LaunchBrowser "MOBILE_CHROME", "Apple_5s", "Apple", "IOS", "10.1.3"

    WebUtil.LaunchMobileBrowserWithID Browser, device_ostype, device_id
    WebUtil.LaunchMobileBrowserWithID "MOBILE_CHROME", "IOS", "02"
```

Source with more info: [6 ways to launch your application](https://www.learnqtp.com/ways-to-launch-your-application/)

Answer (score 0):

I've found [one way](http://www.streamreader.org/askubuntu/questions/35392/how-to-launch-a-new-instance-of-google-chrome-from-the-command-line) using `--user-data-dir=/some/directory`:

```
call Shell.Run("""%userprofile%\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"" --user-data-dir=/some/directory "http://www.google.com", 1, true)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this command to open the Google home page:

```
call Systemutil.Run("http:www.google.com, 1, true)
```

It opened Google home page without any errors.

Comment: Is this QTP specific? I get "Object Required: 'SystemUtil'" when I try and run your code...